# python how can i display a checkbox as checked in

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a GUI with many check boxes (in python).
users should click many check boxes to run the application.
I want to create a button that automatically select and "clicks" some predefined check boxes.

I know how to create the button, and also have the application "know" the check box is checked.

however, when looking at the GUI, the check boxes are left empty, so the user doesn't know which check box is checked.
see below the check box definition:

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.legacyrunsens, 
        QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("stateChanged(int)")), legacychecksens)
```

so, I call `legacychecksens(2)` , but on the GUI the checkbox is not marked.

Comment: PyQt4, PyQt5, PySide or PySide2?

Comment: I'm using PyQt4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution consists of connecting the `clicked` signal to the `setChecked(True)` method of the `QCheckBox` through `functools.partial()`, in the following part I show the example with `PySide4`

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from functools import partial


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        button = QtGui.QPushButton("Default")
        lay.addWidget(button)

        options = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
        default = ["A", "B", "C"] 

        for option in options:
            checkbox = QtGui.QCheckBox(option)
            lay.addWidget(checkbox)
            if option in default:
                button.clicked.connect(partial(checkbox.setChecked, True))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I'm using PyQt4

Comment: @MosheGabay if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank